# Calling JNI c++ methods directly from C++ possible?

Tags: c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, jniwrapper

Is it possible to call a JNI c++ method (which is normally only used from Java) from c++ 
Lets say there is an Android library which uses JNI methods and I want to use these methods directly from my c++ code instead of creating a Java layer. Is this possible? I can't modify the JNI method, I don't know what happens in the JNI method so I can't use the public c++ methods directly and I dont want to pass data up do java just to the pass it down again through the jni interface

Comment: A JNI function may in principle perform arbitrary interactions with the JVM in which it's running (e.g. load classes, call functions), which is outside your control. Sure you can *call* the JNI function, but can you meet its preconditions? You'll probably need to pass it a valid JVM reference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible.
You can can create APK without the java layer.

If want to go with reference example.Try to make with simple example of opengl es.

[Android Native Sample](http://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_na.html)

ie. You can have direct access for the Android layer.